# SpotFire: adding calculated column with reference to two (or more) consecutive rows

Tags: spotfire

I've got a hugh amount of data, with lots of columns.

- 1st column is Installation.
- 2nd column is Sub-Installation
- 3rd column is begin date/time of malfunction
- 4th column is end date/time of malfunction
- 5th column is duration of malfunction

This is what I need:

Sometimes multiple records should be shown as one record (at least the duration.
So this means, if:

- installation of 2 following records is the same AND from the same records
- sub-installation of 2 following records is the same
- the begin date/time of the 2nd record is within the end date/time + 5min of the 1st record

these records durations should be added together.

It could be that 2 records should be 1 record, but it could also be that 8 consecutively records should be 1 record.

```
Ins   Sub-In   Begin         End            Dur   Tot Dur  
x     1        1-1-15 00:00  1-1-15 00:03   3       11  
x     1        1-1-15 00:04  1-1-15 00:12   8       11  
x     1        1-1-15 00:18  1-1-15 00:22   4       4  
z     2        1-1-15 01:00  1-1-15 01:06   6       35  
z     2        1-1-15 01:07  1-1-15 01:16   9       35  
z     2        1-1-15 01:18  1-1-15 01:38   20      35   
z     2        1-1-15 01:45  1-1-15 01:49   4       9  
z     2        1-1-15 01:49  1-1-15 01:54   5       9
```

In above example the column Tot Dur is the one I want to realise.

As you can see the 1st 2 records have the same Inst (x) & Sub-Inst (1) and the begin date/time of the 2nd is within the end dat/time + 5min of the 1st record.
Therefore both durations are add and shown for both records in column Tot Dur: 11 (3+8).

Records 4->9 all have the same Inst (z) & Sub-Inst (2) but between records 6 and 7 the begin and end date/time differ more then 5 min (01:45 - 01:38 = 7 min).

Because the begin and end date/times of records 4->6 are all within 5 min, these are all 1 record and their durations are added: 35 (6+9+20).

Tried to use the OVER function with Intersect but it didn't work.
I think the solutions lies in these functions but can't get the right formula.

If the solution can be done via adding more then 1 calculated column that's also perfectly fine.

*UPDATE* *UPDATE* *UPDATE* *UPDATE*

I’ve narrowed it down to the following.

```
Ins   Sub-In   Begin         End            Dur   Same  Tot Dur  
x     1        1-1-15 00:00  1-1-15 00:03   3    8142    11  
x     1        1-1-15 00:04  1-1-15 00:12   8    Yes     11  
x     1        1-1-15 00:18  1-1-15 00:22   4    No      4  
z     2        1-1-15 01:00  1-1-15 01:06   6    9843    35  
z     2        1-1-15 01:07  1-1-15 01:16   9    Yes     35  
z     2        1-1-15 01:18  1-1-15 01:38   20   Yes     35   
z     2        1-1-15 01:45  1-1-15 01:49   4    6542    9  
z     2        1-1-15 01:49  1-1-15 01:54   5    Yes     9
```

The only thing that now has to happen is a new calculated row, which puts the RowId (8142, 9843, 6542) of the former row if there’s a yes in column Same.

Then the calculation of the Tot Dur is easy.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to handle the ‘Same’ column in the update.
I agree that the idea is that we find a way to group the rows that should be agglomerated. I tried a solution but it did cost me a few calculated columns. Maybe it helps and/or you can combine it with the insight from your update.

Firstly, create a row id: we need it to enumerate the rows

```
[ID]: RowId()
```

Then create a group concatenating Ins and Sub-In: we need it to identify where we want to re-start accumulating the date differences

```
[group]:  Concatenate([Ins],[Sub-In])
```

Then create a column that gives the end of the previous row, or if there is no previous row, adds 10 minutes to the end of the current row (so we can ignore it later on):

```
[EndPrevious]:   SN(Min([End]) over (Previous([End])),DateAdd(“mi”,10,[End]))
```

At this point we can create a running identifier of the groups of rows that could be summed together, as they have start and end within 5 minutes:

```
[startGroup]: Sum(If(DateDiff('mi',[EndPrevious],[Begin])<=5,0,1)) over 
(intersect(Allprevious([ID]),[group])) + DenseRank([group])
```

Here when If(DateDiff('mi',[EndPrevious],[Begin])<=5,0,1) is 0 if we are still within the same start-group, and 1 if we are starting a new one. It could be set as a separated column for clarity, but I wanted to save on the number of columns.

Finally, calculate the sum of durations within [startGroup]:

```
[TotDur2]:  Sum([Dur]) over ([startGroup])
```